# How to install golang with Snappy package manager in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, golang

When I try to install golang with [Snap](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) I get this error message:

```
$ sudo snap install go
error: snap "go" requires classic or confinement override
```

Running snap 2.23.6 on Ubuntu 16.10 with 4.8.0-47-generic Kernel

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo snap install --classic go
```

Comment: i tried this on ubuntu 14.04 and it succeeded but then typing `go version` says `bash: /usr/bin/go: No such file or directory`. where is `go` installed?